# Asp.NET MVC How to end request before action execution end?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My task is to deliver request content before the request has been processed. 
How can I do that?

```
 public ActionResult UpdateRecord()
 {                        
        Response.Write("OK");
        Response.End();
        // I need to complete the request here and           
        // perform some action in the work thread
        Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        return Content("Something user never sees");
 }
```

Comment: Any reason not to spin off the further work into the thread pool – does it need the context/state of the request?

Comment: Yes, it needs very complex context environment with db-transactions, etc. This reason why I cannot use new thread.

Comment: Do you want to do some asynchronous task in the action method?

Comment: To clarify, when you say "Something user never sees" do you mean that your problem is that the user never sees it, or that you don't want the user to see it?  If the latter, why are you returning any thing at all?

Comment: I want user see only "OK" as soon as possible. But now page loading is suspending for 2 seconds by Sleep. I'm looking for way to return all data to client and close connection, and perform some actions after that in work thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send content back to the client in the same request after the request has ended.  It's just not possible.

It sounds to me like what you actually want is an asynchronous processing request.  This is where you start a process in one request, then you continue to poll the server (refresh the page) periodically until the request is done.

This is typically accomplished using a background service of some kind, such as a Message Queue, or Web Service that triggers a Windows Service to process something.  In a pinch, you can use the a Scheduled Task, or even a Cache removal callback trick as well.

Using a background thread won't generally work because threads started by an ASP.NET worker process are terminated after the request ends.

Another possibility, if you don't want to use polling is to use a push service like SignalR to signal the page that the job has been finished.

EDIT:

Well, as I said, you can't do it like that.  You have to push that work into some kind of background process, however you can't just spin off a thread because threads will get terminated once the request ends.

There are many questions (and answers) here on SO on how to do this, and they all boil down to what I mentioned above.  Scheduled tasks, windows service to do the processing, the Cache removal callback trick, etc.. you could also use a WCF one-way call with a WCF service or any of a number of other ways.

Comment: In my case I don't want to send anything to client after Response.End(); I just want to end request and perform some actions after that. But Response.End(); does not actually close connection.